# Android Proguard issue

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-jetpack

I have been using android jetpack, debug works completely fine but as soon as i try to build signed apk with minify enabled true i am facing this issue

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lq0;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:10)
    at c.i.d.k.a(SourceFile:65)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.a(SourceFile:35)
    at c.i.d.k.a(SourceFile:65)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(SourceFile:3)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(SourceFile:6)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(SourceFile:1)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(SourceFile:2)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(SourceFile:15)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(SourceFile:5)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(SourceFile:4)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(SourceFile:5)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy2.callUpgradeApi(Unknown Source)
    at c.a.b.b.a.c$a.run(SourceFile:7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Proguard rules are as follows

```
-dontnote

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-forceprocessing

-optimizationpasses 5

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
   public static *** d(...);
   public static *** v(...);
   public static *** i(...);
   public static *** w(...);
   public static *** e(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects class com.highorbit.jobseeker.util.helperUtils.Logger {
   public static *** d(...);
   public static *** e(...);
}

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**


-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{}
```

Also another thing i am unable to resolve is i am unable to get the exact file name and line number of crash. i have added all the proguard rules for crashlytics but still no success

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your JSON model classes with `@Keep`

Example:

```
// all classes in a package
-keep class com.example.app.json.** { *; }
// or a specific class
-keep class com.example.app.json.SpecificClass { *; }
```

Hope it will work. Thank you.

Comment: i have already anontated all my model classes with serialized name

Comment: I can't see that in your proguard rules file.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for Retrofit Proguard.

```
-keepattributes Signaturec
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }

-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
```

But it's also helpful.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro